# Avoid default Printing of pytest logs when using Live log set up

Tags: python, logging, output, pytest

During Pytest Execution, I see `pytest` logs getting printed after my methods inside `test file` gets executed.

I already use Live log set up to get logs promptly with a desired format. but these pytest logs which are printed RED in color vitiates the entire appeal of the console making things cumbersome. Something like this:

[image]

Upon debugging a bit I traced out `call_and_report`method in `runner.py` module has `log=true` as it's default parameter which is causing this issue. I believe there should be some option to suppress this.

Can someone help me in getting rid of this issue...

**Please be noted that usage of `pytest -s` and other likely stuff is tried and none worked.**

Comment: Did you try `pytest -q` ?

Comment: Yes @blues. that didn't make any difference.